# Spring properties loading from properties file

Tags: java, spring, maven, maven-assembly-plugin, properties-file

I hope this is not a duplicate, but I'm failing to find an answer:

I have a Java Spring application with beans.xml:

```
...
<bean id="config" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
  <property name="locations">
     <list>
       <value>classpath:app.properties</value>
       <value>classpath:app-dev-overrides.properties</value>
     </list>
  </property>
</bean>
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">    
  <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
  <property name="properties" ref="config" />
</bean>
...
```

And a structure looking like this:

```
src/main/resources/
   beans.xml
   db-beans.xml
   app.properties
   app-dev-overrides.properties
   wrapper.conf
src/main/shell
   app.sh
   custom-script.sh
src/main/wrapper
   wrapper.so
   wrapper
   wrapper.jar
```

And I'm assembling this into a DIR using **maven-assembly-plugin** with dist.xml looking like this:

```
<id>dist</id>
<formats>
  <format>dir</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<dependencySets>
  <dependencySet>
     <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
     <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
<fileSets>
<fileSet>
  <!--Get the generated application jar-->
  <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
  <outputDirectory>./</outputDirectory>
  <includes>
    <include>*.jar</include>
  </includes>
</fileSet>
<fileSet>
  <!--Get application prod resources (generally bean XMLs and properties files)-->
  <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
  <excludes>
    <exclude>app-dev-overrides.properties</exclude>
  </excludes>
  <outputDirectory>conf</outputDirectory>
</fileSet>
<fileSet>
  <directory>src/main/shell</directory>
  <outputDirectory>./</outputDirectory>         
  <lineEnding>unix</lineEnding>
  <directoryMode>0755</directoryMode>
</fileSet>
<fileSet>
  <directory>src/main/wrapper</directory>
  <outputDirectory>./bin/</outputDirectory>
  <includes>
    <include>libwrapper.so</include>
    <include>wrapper</include>
  </includes>      
</fileSet>
```

With relevant pom:

```
  <plugins>      
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
      <configuration>
         <finalName>my-app-test</finalName>  
         <archive>
           <manifest>
             <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
             <mainClass>com.test.myapp.Main</mainClass>
             <classpathPrefix>lib</classpathPrefix>
           </manifest>
           <manifestEntries>
             <Class-Path>conf/</Class-Path>
           </manifestEntries>            
         </archive>
       </configuration>
     </plugin>
     <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptors>
           <descriptor>${project.basedir}/src/main/assembly/dist.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
         <finalName>dist</finalName>
         <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
       </configuration>
       <executions>
         <execution>
           <phase>package</phase>
           <goals>
             <goal>directory</goal>
           </goals>
         </execution>
       </executions>
     </plugin>
   </plugins>
```

The objective of this is to have resulting structure:

```
dist/
   bin/"Java Service Wrapper Stuff"
   conf/"Properties and XML"
   lib/"Libraries"
   myApp.sh (java service wrapper shell)
   myApp.jar (target built jar)
```

This works fine for me so far, except that properties and XML files seem to be bundled inside the JAR and changing the resuting conf/app.properties doesn't have an effect on the production server,

So how can I achieve the desired dist structure with configuration loaded on startup rather than being bundled inside the JAR?

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing any script for executing your JAR File? You can easily achieve this by adding the two files from your conf folder on your Classpath while executing the JAR File.

Comment: I'm executing the jar using Java service wrapper [TanukiSoftware](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/introduction.html)

Comment: This is also everything in the POM, whats missing are standard stuff, like artifact/group/version/dependencies....stuff like that.

Comment: From `http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/prop-java-classpath-n.html`. You can do something like: `wrapper.java.classpath.1=../conf/myProps.properties`

Comment: I'm adding ./conf/ to manifest entries: in dist.xml, so my app properties are actually loaded, and @Value annotation works: for example i have a db select limit variable: @Value("${db.limits.selectXXXsize}") which is read from myProps.properties, but in production if you stop the app, and changed it, it doesn't change inside the code, meaning that the actual properties values are bundled inside the JAR, not read from the classpath: myProps.properties

Comment: It is read from the class path. Correct these values from `<value>classpath:app.properties</value>` and `<value>classpath:app-dev-overrides.properties</value>` to `<value>app.properties</value>` and `<value>app-dev-overrides.properties</value>`